# CSS Layout using inline-block leaving gap in parent div

Tags: html, css, layout

This is for an intro to web design course. We're expected to mimic a layout.

I am using inline-block to get the two columns side by side and I'm pleased with the results except for some space to the right of the black main div. I can't figure out why the parent div is not shrinking to fit the inline-block divs.

[Layout with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeQyx.jpg)

I've never used jsfiddle before but this is what I believe is a correct jsfiddle with my html/css code:

https://jsfiddle.net/j8jpqm9p/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<style>
a:link{
    color:#008000;
    font-size:1.15em;
    font-weight:bold;
}
a:hover{
    color:#ccffcc;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.15em;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
body{
    background-color:gray;
}
.container{
    overflow:hidden;
    border-width:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:blue;
    border-radius:25px 25px 25px 25px;
}
.topcont{
    padding:10px 0px 25px 25px;
    background-color:white;

}
.sidecont{
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:200px;
    max-width:300px;
    background-color:green; 
    margin:0px;
    height: 700px;
}
.maincont{
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    width:1000px;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    height:700px;
    margin:0px;
}
.bottomcont{
    background-color:white;
    padding: 0px 0px 25px 10px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="topcont">
        <a href="http://www4.uwm.edu/" target="_blank" >Link One</a> | 
        <a href="http://www.uwgb.edu/" target="_blank" >Link Two</a> | 
        <a href="http://www.uwosh.edu/" target="_blank" >Link Three</a> | 
        <a href="http://www.wisc.edu/" target="_blank" >Link Four</a> |
        <a href="http://www.uwec.edu/" target="_blank" >Link Five</a>
        </div>
        <div class="sidecont">The sidebar
        </div><div class="maincont"> Main content of the page goes in this container
        </div>
        <div class="bottomcont">Contact information
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

I tried to post a link to the layout I'm expected to copy but I'm limited to two links due to my rep. It's basically exactly the same, sans the grey space/third column on the right of the black main container.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit to add:
Whatever is causing the parent div (container) to be that large it does not appear to be the topcont or bottomcont divs. I can set those both to width of 50% and they shrink appropriately but the main container div stays as large as it is.

I can manually set the container div down a few % points and minimize the gray gap, but it doesn't go away.

Is there some explicit command to force the container div to shrink to fit it's child divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your .container is not an *inline-block* but a *block* element. And a block element will not wrap around the content, but will always fill the entire available width.

To solve your problem, you can add the following line to .container.

```
display: inline-block;
```

Here is the corrected fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j8jpqm9p/11/
This will make your container an inline-block as well and make it wrap around the content.

---

I'm not sure why you are using min-width and max-width though. This will make the total width of your site dependend on the content in your sidecontainer.  Your site width will be somewhere between 1200px and 1300px, depending on what you put in .sidecont

Usually you'd want your container to have a fixed width and not change depending on the content inside of it.

```
.container{
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.sidecont{
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color:green; 
    height: 700px;
}

.maincont{
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    width:1000px;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    height:700px;
}
```

Notice that we added an extra line to .sidecont:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

This is to make sure the padding of the element does not count against the width of the element. Without this line, your sidecontent block will be 210 pixels wide. (200px + 10px padding)

I hope it solves your problem. Keep in mind though that there are far better ways of constructing these types of grids.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thank you! As for the sidebar width, his exact requirement is "Sidebar (green section) width between 200-300 pixels". I'm not sure if he means that literally or that I can pick some value between the two. I'm torn on which way to submit. I'll probably submit with the variable width and leave a note explaining why I did it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to add a few things if you want to do it this way.

First, you should set set `box-sizing` globally to `border-box` as this will make working with flexible widths much easier.

```
* { 
   box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

Next, you'll need set a percentage width on your columns to allow them to flex and then set a min width of `1000px` to your main content column.

```
.sidecont {
    width: 23.1%; /* 300px/1300px */
    max-width: 300px;
    min-width: 300px;
}

.maincont {
    width: 76.9%; /* 1000px/1300px */
    min-width: 1000px;
}
```

Then, you need to set a min and max width on the container to keep it from growing too large and shrinking too small. You'll also need to give it a `margin: 0 auto` to properly center the container and, since you're using inline-block you'll want to add `white-space: nowrap` to prevent the columns from wrapping.

```
.container {
    min-width: 1200px;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The end result will look like the following:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
a:hover{
 color:#ccffcc;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:1.15em;
 text-decoration:underline;
}
body{
 background-color:gray;
}
.container{
 overflow:hidden;
 border-width:2px;
 border-style:solid;
 border-color:blue;
 border-radius:25px 25px 25px 25px;
    min-width:1200px;
    max-width:1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.topcont{
 padding:10px 0px 25px 25px;
 background-color:white;

}
.sidecont{
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
 display:inline-block;
    width: 23.1%;
 min-width:200px;
 max-width:300px;
 background-color:green; 
 margin:0px;
 height: 700px;
}
.maincont{
 text-align:center;
 display:inline-block;
    width: 76.9%;
 min-width:1000px;
 background-color:black;
 color:white;
 height:700px;
 margin:0px;
}
.bottomcont{
 background-color:white;
 padding: 0px 0px 25px 10px;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="topcont">
        <a href="http://www4.uwm.edu/" target="_blank" >Link One</a> | 
     <a href="http://www.uwgb.edu/" target="_blank" >Link Two</a> | 
     <a href="http://www.uwosh.edu/" target="_blank" >Link Three</a> | 
     <a href="http://www.wisc.edu/" target="_blank" >Link Four</a> |
     <a href="http://www.uwec.edu/" target="_blank" >Link Five</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sidecont">
        The sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="maincont"> 
        Main content of the page goes in this container
    </div>
    <div class="bottomcont">
        Contact information
    </div>
</div>
```

Realistically though, flexbox would be a much better way to go.

Comment: The course hasn't covered flexbox, so I'm solving it with the tools with which we've been provided. However, based on your comment (and other reading) I'm noting flexbox and will do some reading. At an initial glance I don't fully understand what it's doing, but it does seem to be recognized as the best solution for this type of thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width of the container to fit it in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
.sidecont{
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    mirgin:auto;
    background-color:green; 
    height: 700px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried changing the margin to auto but it did not make a difference. The grey bar is still on the right side.

Comment: hey dorz tick on answer